# Facebook Android - Key Hashes validation

Tags: android, facebook, hash, single-sign-on, keytool

I have created key hashes as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) (in the end of step 4):-

They tell password is `android`

It is correct for `debug.keystore` but I have `distr.keystore` with different password

Both passwords worked and produced different key hashes when I used them with `distr.keystore`.

I expected to see: - you have entered wrong password

I think non `android` password is correct one. But how do I test Key Hash that it is correct Key Hash and another isn't.

Answer (score 0):

u said the both passwords worked with different key hashes , try to use both of them in the facebook side and enter each key hash and try to use your application . it should work if the key hash is right , and the program shouldn't work if the key hash is wrong. but why do u use another file rather than the debug.keystore ?

Comment: Facebook allows to enter multiple key hashes. First one is development that eclipse uses by default and second one is used for google play submission. I can also get correct Key Hash from `PackageInfo.signatures` I mostly wondering how to validate key hash with `keytool` or some similar way to ensure that key signature is correct. There could be different reasons that app does not work with FB or even works when something wrong.